# Converting a Specific mysql query to a general one

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL query that generates a pivot based on certain data that I stored in a separate table from the main table. The query for the pivot table is

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SET @@group_concat_max_len = 5000;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(IF(cropname = ''',
      cropname,
      ''', quantity, NULL)) AS ''',
      cropname,''''
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM
  tempcrop;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT date, SUM(quantity),', @sql, ' FROM tempcrop Group By date');

  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt;
```

Now I need to convert this query so that I don't have to create a separate table and the pivot table can be created directly using the main table.

The query from which I the data for 'Tempcrop' table is

```
Select str_to_date(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d') Timestamp, value as Cropname, Count(*) Quantity from logs where key='crop_selected' 
GROUP BY STR_TO_DATE(Timestamp,'%Y-%m-%d'), Value
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(Timestamp,'%Y-%m-%d'), COUNT(*) DESC;
```

How can I create the Pivot directly from this query without using Tempcrop table.

Comment: If you need a dynamic number of columns in your pivot query, then why would you want to move away from dynamic SQL?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm not moving away from dynamic sql. I want to remove the need to create a separate table from the main table and create the pivot table. I would I like to create the pivot table dynamically from the main table.